# JSP User Interface options

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, user-interface

I am working on a Web application. I use Tomcat as the servlet container. Right now, I am using JSP Scriptlets to render the html forms and elements. However, I have heard that using Scriptlets have become a taboo nowadays. So what are the available options/alternatives that are simple and easy way ?

EDIT : My design is MVC, then question will be "available options to the View part".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to make your project designed using MVC. The business logic should be separated from the user-interface. You should handle your logic in your `servlet` classes instead.

Edit:
You could use `JSTL` in your JSP for handling simple logic. Start reading about JSTL core. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just edited my question. Yes, its MVC, so what are the good options for the View part ?